# Firefox NPAPI Xcode link errors

Tags: macos, firefox, plugins, npapi

I'm trying to build a Firefox plugin for Mac OSX, it build well but I don't understand why the linker failed.

Here is the log of the linker:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_NPN_ReleaseVariantValue", referenced from:
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
  "_NPN_MemAlloc", referenced from:
      String2Variant(_NPVariant*, char const*)in plugin.o
  "_NPN_GetValue", referenced from:
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
  "_NPN_ReleaseObject", referenced from:
      CPlugin::~CPlugin()in plugin.o
      CPlugin::~CPlugin()in plugin.o
  "_NPN_Version", referenced from:
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
  "_NPN_UserAgent", referenced from:
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
  "_NPN_GetProperty", referenced from:
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
  "_NPN_GetURL", referenced from:
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnZoomChange()       in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnPIPMove()       in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnItem(int, bool)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnClose(char const*)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnWheel(int)    in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnRightClick(int, int)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnKeyPress(unsigned short)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnMouseDn(int, int)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnMouseUp(int, int)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnMouseMove(int, int)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnClick(int, int)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnSelect()       in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnStatus(char const*)in CTPlugin.o
      CPluginData::Fire_OnImage(int, int, int, int)in CTPlugin.o
  "_NPN_CreateObject", referenced from:
      CPlugin::GetScriptableObject()      in plugin.o
  "_NPN_GetStringIdentifier", referenced from:
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
      _NPP_New in npp_gate.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
      CPlugin::CPlugin(_NPP*)in plugin.o
  "_NPN_InvalidateRect", referenced from:
      CPluginData::Refresh(bool)  in CTPlugin.o
  "_NPN_RetainObject", referenced from:
      CPlugin::GetScriptableObject()      in plugin.o
```

I really don't understand what I've done bad!
Have I missed libraries to link with? Thanks in advance =)

EDIT: Add code example, for the _NPN_MemAlloc from String2Variant in plugin.o:

```
static void String2Variant(NPVariant *result, LPCTSTR value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            ClassUnicode cu;
            char *utf8String = cu.CurrentModeToUTF8(value);

            uint32 len = (uint32) strlen(utf8String);
            char *clone = (char *)NPN_MemAlloc(len+1);
            memcpy(clone,utf8String,len);
            clone[len] = '\0';
        } else
        {
            result->type = NPVariantType_String;
            result->value.stringValue.UTF8Characters = NULL;
            result->value.stringValue.UTF8Length = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no library that provides `NPN_MemAlloc`, it is actually one of the callbacks that you get when the browser calls [`NP_Initialize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NP_Initialize). You need to store the `aNPNFuncs` parameter so that you can use it later:

```
static NPNetscapeFuncs *sBrowserFuncs;

NPError NP_Initialize(NPNetscapeFuncs *aNPNFuncs, NPPluginFuncs *aNPPFuncs)
{
   // Sanity checks go here

   sBrowserFuncs = aNPNFuncs;
}
```

When you need to call `NPN_MemAlloc` you do it like this:

```
sBrowserFuncs->memalloc(len+1);
```

Or you actually define the function `NPN_MemAlloc`, the way the [test plugin](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/test/testplugin/nptest.cpp) does it:

```
void*
NPN_MemAlloc(uint32_t size)
{
  return sBrowserFuncs->memalloc(size);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I assume I must do something approaching for others functions? What the difference between the two solutions? And when this hs change in Firefox? Do you have links about that? Again thanks for your help =)

Comment: Yes, you need to do the same thing for other functions as well - simply copying the code from the test plugin should be easiest. There is no real difference between the two solutions, the second approach simply allows you to leave your other code unchanged (it can continue calling `NPN_MemAlloc` rather than calling `sBrowserFuncs->memalloc`). And - this didn't change, it has always been like this (see http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Internet/Netscape%20Plug-Ins/ch8.htm, this explanation talks about Netscape **Navigator** 3.0 which is ancient).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I asked about the change because this plugin built with xulrunner < 1.8

Comment: I looked through the source code of Firefox 1.0 (meaning Gecko 1.7.5) just to be sure but I didn't find any relevant differences there.

Comment: Well I said that because this plugin use the npupp.h file which was removed from the SDK and I'm trying to port it to the new SDK. Maybe I did a mistake and my linker errors come from that.

Comment: `npupp.h` was part of the ActiveX embedding API, it has been removed in [bug 662023](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662023).